# Is there absolutely NO way in Java to pass the object itself to a method so it actually gets changed?

Tags: java, parameters, methods

```
class MetaData {
    public String version;
    public String compression;
}
```

I make a MetaData object, pass it into a method, and fill the version and compression fields from within the method. And I want these changes to exist outside of the lifetime of the method. In C++ I think I added a & or something to pass the object itself and not a copy of it to the method. Is there ANYWAY to do the same in Java?

Comment: This question seems backwards. If you pass this object to a function, and the function changes version and compression, the new values WILL be visible to the caller. The thing that would make changes invisible would be if you changed the MetaData reference to a new value.

Comment: well, unfortunately, that's not the case. thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will always happen in Java.  It's just the way Java works.  When you pass a "MetaData" object to a method, a reference to that object is passed and any modifications made to its "version" and "compression" fields should be seen everywhere.

Check out this article for a really in-depth explanation:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Answer (score 5):

[Java has pass by value semantics](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm). This does not mean that objects are passed by value to methods. Rather, it means that references to objects are passed by value to methods.

So in this scenario, when you create a MetaData object, and pass it to a method where in the fields are populated, the reference to the object is passed to that method. Once the method returns, you can examine the object reference in the caller to confirm that its fields have been set.

By the way, this is a bad practice in OOP, if you are sending a MetaData object to another class for setting the state of the object. Objects themselves should be in charge of their state.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behaviour in Java.

```
class Example {
   public static void doit(MetaData data) {
     data.compression = "Testing"
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     MetaData data = new MetaData();
     doit(data);
     System.out.println(data.compression);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All mutable objects you pass to methods can be changed, and the original will change.  The problem is that String cannot be changed--it is immutable.

Pass an object that can be changed.

If you want to change "version", then give your class "MetaData" a .setVersion() method and pass "MetaData" to your method.  Your method would call metaData.setVersion("I'm NEW"); and everyone will be happy.

```
public void willWorkFine (Metadata metaData) {
    metaData.setVersion("Changed!");
}
```

What you can't do is pass "version" to a method expecting a String and re-assign it:

```
public void wontWork(String changeMe) {
    changeMe="not changed!";
}
```

Since changeMe is just a local reference to the original "version" object, reassigning your local reference to point to a different object has no effect on the outside program.